# How long can I draw 5 Amps from AAAA batery

Tags: batteries, series

So this question might sound a bit weird, but if I had 14 rechargeable AAAA Battery strung together in series so the total voltage out put is 16.8 Volts, how long could I draw 5 Amps from the batteries before I cause damage to the batteries or the voltage drops below 15.6 Volts?

Comment: Most likely you simply cannot draw 5 A without the voltage dropping below 15.6 V, due to internal resistance. Even 1 ohm of internal resistance would drop the output to 11 V.

Comment: I do not think that's practical, but why don't you connect them all together to the 5A device and measure the voltage continuously for say 10 seconds. I would expect them to die pretty fast.

Comment: the answer is: 0s.

Comment: NiCd rechargable cells have very low internal resistance- it's possible you could get 5A for a few seconds. It's also possible the battery pack would literally explode.

Comment: Fine, the OP's proposal is a silly one.  But why downvote it?  There's no such thing as a silly question, only a silly answer.

Answer (score 3):

A short google gave these figures for an AAAA NiMH battery:

- capacity 500 mAh
- Voltage 1.2V
- resistance 50 mOhm

When you draw 5A from such a battery it drops 0.25V (due to its internal resistance), so the voltage you get is 0.95V. Take 14 batteries and you get 13.3 Volt. Hence the correct answer (based on the figures) is indeed 0.

My gut feeling (but I found no figures) is that an AAAA cel is not designed for 5A current and might exhibit 'undesired' behaviour. (Heating up, being damaged, catching fire, exploding). Even 500mA might be too much.

In short: don't do this, switch to 'beefier' cells. D might be a better choice.

Comment: He could always weld with some 9Vs https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7nyQ4pMr9pg